# A função order em R

Tags: r, order

Eu não entendo o que acontece. Observem

```
> x<-c(-2,4,-6,5,9,7)

> x

[1] -2  4 -6  5  9  7

> order(x)

[1] 3 1 2 4 6 5
```

Não entendo porque o vetor x não é ordenado. Reparem, quando dou `order(x)` some o 7

E neste caso? Supostamente não teria que me dar o vetor x ordenado de forma decrescente?

```
> order(x, decreasing=TRUE)

[1] 5 6 4 2 1 3
```

Que coisa estranha!
Ajuda por favor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A função `order` não retorna o vetor original ordenado, mas retorna um vetor com as posições para que `x` fique em ordem crescente.

Dessa forma, para obter de volta o vetor`x` ordenado, você tem que colocar `x[order(x)]`:

```
x[order(x)]
[1] -6 -2  4  5  7  9
```

Ou, em ordem decrescente:

```
x[order(x, decreasing=TRUE)]
[1]  9  7  5  4 -2 -6
```

Caso você queira fazer isso direto, você pode usar a função `sort`, que já te retorna o vetor ordenado ao invés das posições:

```
sort(x)
[1] -6 -2  4  5  7  9
```

Ou:

```
sort(x, decreasing=TRUE)
[1]  9  7  5  4 -2 -6
```

Comment: Muito obrigado... agora entendi

Comment: @Vasco por nada! Se a resposta atendeu à sua dúvida, você pode aceitá-la, abs!